# Angular - routerLink - Focus

Tags: angular, typescript, focus, router, routerlink

I'm having trouble with focus on routerLink.

The first line shows the perfect URL with the theoretical focus but doesn't focus on anything.
The second line focus well but reloads the complete page.
What can I do to use routerLink and focus on a specific input?

Origin: Component1

```
<a [routerLink]="'first'" fragment="name"> first </a>


<a href="{{ '/first#name' }}"> first </a>
```

Target: component2

```
<input
#name
id="name"
matInput
(ngModelChange)="change()"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enable `anchorScrolling` in your app-routing module.

```js
const routes: Routes = [{ ... }];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { anchorScrolling: 'enabled' })],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

I don't know why this is disabled by default.

If the link is clickable more than once you will have to set `onSameUrlNavigation` to `'reload'` as well.

```js
const routes: Routes = [{ ... }];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
      anchorScrolling: 'enabled',
      onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload',
    }),
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

See all of the options here: https://angular.io/api/router/ExtraOptions